# R stm - Number of provided texts and number of documents modeled do not match

Tags: r, text-mining, topic-modeling

I'm working with textual data from abstracts and I am trying to use `stm` (structural topic modeling) to have a look on unsupervised extracted topics, before constructing my own dictionary (for supervised analysis). 
I'm dealing with a problem and I wonder whether anyone had encountered the same issue before. 
When running `findThoughts()` I get the following error:

> Error in findThoughts(out.stm, topics = 27, texts = corpus$documents$texts,  : 
>     Number of provided texts and number of documents modeled do not match

I'm not sure what's wrong with my data. I thought it could have to do with `NA` values in those empty rows of the corpus wherein I had no abstract, but the same happens after removing `NA` rows (with the following:

```
df[!is.na(df$abstract),]
```

If you have any idea on the matter, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

The findThoughts function returns the error "Number of provided texts and number of documents modeled do not match" when length(texts) != number of rows of out.stm.

This is an error that orginates from the textProcessor function that is used to process the documents before calling the 'stm' function.

Here is why this happens: 
The temp output has an attribute temp$docs.removed which lists the rows that were removed. So the length of 'temp$documents' will be lesser than 'comments' by length of temp$docs.removed.

So the stm object 'a' and a$theta (the matrix with topic probabilities of documents) which is modeled using temp$documents will have the same length as temp$documents.

```
temp<-textProcessor(comments, metadata=NULL,  lowercase=TRUE, removestopwords=TRUE, removenumbers=TRUE,  removepunctuation=TRUE, stem=TRUE, wordLengths=c(3,Inf),  sparselevel=1, language="en",  verbose=TRUE, onlycharacter= FALSE, striphtml=FALSE, customstopwords=NULL, onlytxtfiles=TRUE)


meta<-temp$meta
vocab<-temp$vocab
docs<-temp$documents
a<-stm(documents=docs, vocab=vocab, K=7,data=meta, max.em.its=800)
```

Solution: Remove the documents that were removed in the 'temp' object from your 'texts' objects. The code below does that by creating a new vector z that removes the indices referenced in temp$docs.removed.

```
z<-comments[-temp$docs.removed,]
length(z)

thoughts3 <- findThoughts(a,texts=z,topics=3, n=10,thresh=0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to answer given by Sruthi Susan Thomas, the correct code working for me was put the "**out**" imput (out=prepDocuments(text$documents,text$vocab,text$meta)) instead "temp" in the argument. **Out** have the correct indexes of documents removed.